# Рисунки с разными разрешениями

Tags: html, css, изображения

Есть 2 изображения: одно с разрешением 100 на 100, другое 300 на 300. Будут ли они выглядеть одинаково или второй вариант лучше?

```
<img id="aaa" src="1.png" />\\100 на 100
<img id="aaa2" src="2.png" />\\300 на 300
<style>
    #aaa {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
    #aaa2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 120px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
</style>
```

Есть такая мода в новой технике: делать большое разрешение (но с невеликими размерами). То есть там пикселей на см, или дюйм в квадрате очень много (по сравнению с более ранними дисплеями). По логике там с большим разрешением будет лучше 300 на 300 чем 100 на 100. Это так или нет? Просто я думаю, что в таком примере (100 на 100 с большими разрешениями) придется несколькими пикселями показывать 1 пиксель картинки. А если 300, то я думаю будет норм, или нет? Но если смотреть картинку 300 на 300 на старом дисплее, она будет выглядеть как без сглаживания?
А CSS сжимает рисунки, или делает перед выводом на экран изменения разрешения рисунка?
Или это все бред?

Comment: Одинаково.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Большой размер:

```
 + высокое качество 
 + не будет выглядеть плохо на старых экранах
 - больше трафика
```

Маленький размер:

```
 + Меньше трафика
 - Не очень чётко на современных дисплеях
 - УЖАСНО и размыто выглядит на retina дисплеях
```

Comment: Большой размер: - Ето когда изображения 300 на 300 всунуто черес CSS в 100 на 100?Или просто 1 к 1?

Comment: @Олег24 300x300 ==> 100x100

Comment: Ясно,спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

На таких размерах полностью одинаково будут выглядеть.

а вот 3000х3000 и 1000х1000 при масштабировании средствами CSS то больший размер будет все таки предпочтительней.

Comment: А почему:
"а вот 3000х3000 и 1000х1000 при масштабировании средствами CSS то больший размер будет все таки предпочтительней."???

Answer (score 1):

[@Олег24](/users/10758/%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B324), почитайте [**здесь**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), [**здесь**](http://www.fortress-design.com/kak-vliyaet-uvelichenie-rastrovogo-izobrazheniya-na-kachestvo/), и **здесь**.

Надеюсь, все станет ясно.

Comment: Ето я знал,а третяя ссилка на сам вопрос). Но мой вопрос не в етом.Вопрос в том ,стоит ли брать изображение 300 на 300 и сжимать ево черес CSS до 100 на 100.И что при етом будет с качеством.

Comment: @Олег24, если Вы сожмете изображение 300х300 до 100х100, то ничего страшного не произойдет(не потеряете в качестве). А если 300х300 увеличите до 1000х1000, то потеря качества будет очевидной. Обратное тоже верно. В ссылках, которые я указал, об этом написано.

Comment: Я знаю ,что если с большего в меньше - бес потерь качества,
А с меньшего в большее -потеря большая,
А если мне надо на сайте заполнить какойто див размером 100 на 100 ,а я в папке с изображениям сайта закину картинку большего размера(например 500 на 500),но в CSS поставлю ширину 100 и висоту 100.Будет тогда мой див лучше виглядеть,чем когда возьму тоже изображения и в паинте ево изменю до 100 на 100 и вставлю вместо первого изображения(того что 500 на 500)?И стоит ли так делать?Или не будет разницы?

Comment: Бес потерь качества - это серьезная проблема, да. Бесов надо гнать.